# Iterate through a replaceWith function

Tags: jquery, loops, replacewith

Is there a best way to consolidate this? I've added a Clear button under each file input, but `replaceWith` has to reflect a certain name (ex. `name="file-490"`) for each field. The `name` can be sequential, i.e. 491, 492, 493.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clear1").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#control1").replaceWith('<input id="control1" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file " type="file" aria-invalid="false" name="file-490" novalidate="novalidate">');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clear2").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#control2").replaceWith('<input id="control2" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file " type="file" aria-invalid="false" name="file-491" novalidate="novalidate">');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clear3").click(function(event){ ( etc.)
```

I think I'd have to put the selector inside an each function like `$("#clear").each(function(event){` but not sure how to go about creating a loop to iterate through adding numbers to each element.

```
$("#clear").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#control' +(i+1)+' ").replaceWith('<input id="control' +(i+1)+ '" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file " type="file" aria-invalid="false" name="file-49' +(i+1)+ '" novalidate="novalidate">');
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You haven't shown your HTML, but it should be possible to do this with a single click handler if you group the 'clear' buttons with a class, then find the related input using a DOM traversal method, such as `prev()` or `next()`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and post again.